# Golang exercise slices how does it deal with big values

Tags: go

I'm going through the Golang tutorial and I'm a little bit confused as to what it is doing with some of the values in the slices exercise. https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/18

Here is the code that I am confused with:

A value of 0 is a perfectly blue pixel and a value of 255 is a perfectly white pixel. So what is happening here when the value displayed is some form of `x*y` (I did `/20` to make the image a little bit bigger and easier to see).

If you follow the image horizontally, you will see that at some point in the process, the ever increasing x and y values seem to revert to blue (0 value) If I type a static value like `256` in the return I get a compile error. So it obviously does not allow the numbers to `go off the scale` and revert to 0 or anything. So how does it get the blue curves in the picture?

imported source here: https://github.com/golang/tour/blob/master/pic/pic.go#L15

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    //First, the array has to be made so we can put some values in it later
    //This only makes the second dimension of the array ([[uint8 dy]])?
    image := make([][]uint8, dy)

    //The inputs into the function are Int's, so it is ok to have a non uint8
    //loop initializer
    for x := 0; x < dy; x++ {
        //once we are in the loop we have to make the first dimension of the array
        //based on the dx values
        image[x] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for y := 0; y < dx; y++ {
            //This is a function +to assign the pixel values to the array
            image[x][y] = uint8((x * y) /20)
        }
    }
    return image
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine `i` is of type `int`, `uint8(i)` returns [Least Significant Byte (LSB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit)  of `i`:

When `x` is in range `[0, 255]` , meaning: `0 <= x <= 255`
and `y` is in range [0, 255],
then `x*y` is in range `[0, 255*255] = [0, 65025]`
so `x*y/20` is in range `[0, 255*255/20] = [0, 65025/20] = [0, 3251]`
and value of `uint8(x*y/20)` is equal to `(x*y/20)%256` meaning exactly LSB byte:
`uint8(3251) = uint8(0XCB3) = 0XB3 = 179`
`3251 = 12*256 + 179`

So every time the `x*y/20` is bigger than 255 it counts from 0 again: `(x*y/20) % 256` this is why your image is repeated circles.

Try this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for y := 0; y <= 255; y++ {
        for x := 0; x <= 255; x++ {
            v := x * y / 20
            if int(uint8(v)) != v%256 {
                fmt.Println(v, v%256)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

output:

```
Done.
```

Let's simplify you example, see this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    const dx = 256
    const dy = 256
    m := image.NewNRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, dx, dy))
    for y := 0; y < dy; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < dx; x++ {
            v := uint8(x * y / 20)
            i := y*m.Stride + x*4
            m.Pix[i] = v     //R
            m.Pix[i+1] = v   //G
            m.Pix[i+2] = 255 //B
            m.Pix[i+3] = 255 //A
        }
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := png.Encode(&buf, m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(buf.Bytes())
}
```

And redirect the output to a file like `main > b.png` or, `go run main.go > b.png`
see output file `b.png`:
[image]

Comment: @deltaskelta why does it fail when you enter `uint8(256)`? yes `uint8(256)` gives `constant 256 overflows uint8` but `var i int = 256
 fmt.Println(uint8(i))`  gives `0`, see: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16153

Answer (score 1):

`uint8(anotherIntValue)` conversion will take the last byte of `anotherIntValue`. That is why your code can produce many blue (0). For example, following code would print 'val = 0'.

```
dx, dy := 128, 2
fmt.Println("val =", uint8(dx*dy))
```

Constant conversion will be checked by compiler for out of range errors.

Comment: then why does it fail when I enter `uint8(256)`..it says it overflows uint8

Comment: It is because constant conversion is subject to different static checking rule. Reference can be found at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions. Specifically T(x) is good when x is constant AND 'x is representable by a value of type T.' int8(256) fails because 256 is beyond what one byte can represent.